# Perl 'can't locate object method "worksheets" via package "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook"'

Tags: excel, perl, parsing

I am trying to open two Excel .xls files for comparing. I included

```
    use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
```

then, I continue my code as follow:

```
    my $parser_r   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
    my $resultbook = $parser_r->parse($absPathResult);
    my $parser_i   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
    my $resultideal = $parser_i->parse($absPathIdeal);

    @worksheetsListResult = $resultbook->worksheets();
    @worksheetsListIdeal = $resultideal->worksheets();
```

the first error I encountered was "can't locate object method "parser"...", but that was solved by changing "parser" to "Parser".

When I execute the script again, I am getting the error: can't locate object method "worksheets" via package "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook".

I am running the script in Linux, Perl v5.8.5.

Any idea what is the possible problem here? I am new to Perl language. All comments are very much appreciated.

PS: When I run the similar code in Windows, everything is working perfectly.

Comment: That version of Perl is 11 years old.  Consider an upgrade with [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The workbooks() method was added in 0.43](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel#L275), six years ago.  Since your version of Perl is rather old (11 years), it's likely your version of Spreadsheet::ParseExcel is also rather old.

You can check with:

```
perl -MSpreadsheet::ParseExcel -wle 'print $Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::VERSION'
```

In general, don't use the web documentation for Perl modules unless you're keeping up to date.  It probably won't be for your installed version.  Instead use [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.html).